# byebug and web-console not working in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

In my Rails application, I am able to use byebug in controller.

However, neither adding `byebug` or `console` in view is helping me to get a debug console.

I am using Haml, thus it's not `<% console %>`. In other words, the lines (one of the two at-a-time) I used in the view are:

```
byebug
console
```

I haven't tried Pry or Pry-debug, but apparently they also don't work in views?

Am I using these gems incorrectly or is there another way to add debugs in views?

Thanks,
Kumar.

Comment: Let us know what you tried? Means how you added `byebug` in `haml` view?

Comment: Just "byebug" (without quotes) in a line by itself

Comment: So, just try `- byebug` or `= byebug` as mentioned in the following answers. Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

try doing `- byebug` on its own line

Answer (score 6):

To expand on @bf34's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35942913/385532), you may just need to tell haml that `byebug` is code that needs to be run. You can do this by preceding it with `-` (e.g. `- byebug`) as explained in the [HAML reference](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#running_ruby_)

Comment: That's helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

For me, this one here worked

```
<% byebug %>
```

Hope it does for you too!